# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child while using react-bootstrap-table-next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I have a React component where I am trying to render a table using the react-bootstrap-table-next library. I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

**Issue:** The `array` that I am passing has a property which is an object itself. Where `<BootstrapTable>` can take only `string` as property. If you look at the screenshot of the `console.log(todos)`, it shows the `dueDate` property is an object instead of `string`.

**Tried:**

```
const columns = [
    { dataField: 'title', text: 'Title'},
    { dataField: 'description', text: 'Description' },
    { dataField: 'dueDate', text: 'Due Date' }
  ];

return (
        <div>
           <BootstrapTable 
            keyField= 'id'
            data={todos}
            columns={columns}
           />
        </div>
    );
```

When I try to enter some data, todos are `console.log` like below:
[image]

**Problem:** Nothing renders inside the `BootstrapTable` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with `<BootstrapTable>` is that it doesn't take `object` as one of its `property` `value`. It has to be `string`:

In my component, the `onFormSubmit` method had a date as `new Date()`. But that is just a `Date` `object`. So it needed parsing with `JSON` `Serializer`.

**Solution**

`dueDate: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dueDate))`

[Source](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jan/06/javascript-json-date-parsing-and-real-dates):

> ```
> var date = new Date();
> console.log(date); // Wed Jan 01 2014 13:28:56 GMT-1000 (Hawaiian Standard Time) 
>         
> var json = JSON.stringify(date);
> console.log(json);  // "2014-01-01T23:28:56.782Z"
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> // JSON encoded date
> var json = "\"2014-01-01T23:28:56.782Z\"";
>
> var dateStr = JSON.parse(json);  
> console.log(dateStr); // 2014-01-01T23:28:56.782Z
>         
> var date = new Date(dateStr);
> console.log(date);  // Wed Jan 01 2014 13:28:56 GMT-1000 (Hawaiian Standard Time)
> ```